# I've got a django site with a good deal of javascript but my clients have terrible connectivity - how to optimize?

Tags: django, apache, caching

We're hosting a django service for some clients using really really poor and intermittent connectivity.  Satellite and GPRS connectivity in parts of Africa that haven't benefited from the recent fiber cables making landfall.

I've consolidated the javascripts and used minificatied versions, tried to clean up the stylesheets, and what not...

Like a good django implementer, I'm letting apache serve up all the static information like css and JS and other static media.  I've enabled apache modules `deflate` (for gzip) and `expired` to try to minimize retransmission of the javascript packages (mainly jQuery's huge cost).  I've also enabled django's gzip middleware (but that doesn't seem to do much in combination with apache's deflate).

Main question - what else is there to do to optimize bandwidth utilization?

- Are there django optimizations in headers or what not to make sure that "already seen data" will not travel over the network?
- The django caching framework seems to be tailored towards server optimization (minimize hitting the database) - how does that translate to actual bandwidth utilization?
- what other tweaks on apache are there to make sure that the browser won't try to get data it already has?

Comment: have you used firebug or safari's developer mode to profile the pages yet? They are good tools to determine the actual time & bandwidth cost of the different elements (js/html/images/css/etc). The Yslow plugin for firebug is also a handy profiling tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of your optimizations are important for wringing better performance out of your server, but don't confuse them with optimizing bandwidth utilization.  In other words gzip/deflate are relevant but Apache serving static content is not (even though it is important).

Now, for your problem you need to look at three things: how much data is being sent, how many connections are required to get the data, and how good are the connections.

You mostly have the first area covered by using deflate/gzip, expires, minimization of javascript etc. so I can only add one or two things you might not know about.  First, you should upgrade to Django 1.1, if you haven't already, because it has better support for ETags/Expires headers for your Django views.  You probably already have those headers working properly for static data from Apache but if you're using older Django they (probably) aren't being set properly on your dynamic views.

For the next area, number of connections, you need to consolidate your javascript and css files into as few files as possible to reduce the number of connections.  Also very helpful can be consolidating your image files into a single "sprite" image.  There are a few Django projects to handle this aspect: [django-compress](http://code.google.com/p/django-compress/), [django-media-bundler](http://github.com/rnk/django-media-bundler/tree/master) (which is the only one that will create image sprites), and you can also see [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1199470/combine-javascript-files-at-deployment-in-python).

For the last area of how good are the connections you should look at global CDN as suggested by Alex, or at the very least host your site at an ISP closer to your users.  This could be tough for Africa, which in my experience can't even get decent connectivity into European ISP's (at least southern Africa... northern Africa might be better).

Answer (score 1):

You could delegate jQuery to a CDN which may have better connectivity with Africa, e.g., [google](http://perishablepress.com/press/2008/11/25/save-bandwidth-by-serving-jquery-mootools-prototype-via-googles-ajax-libraries-api/) (and, it's a free service!-). Beyond that I recommend anything every written (or spoken on video, there's a lot of that!-) by [Steve Souders](http://stevesouders.com/) -- while his talks and books and essays are invaluable to EVERY web developer I think they're particularly precious to ones serving a low-bandwidth audience (e.g., one of his tips in his latest books and talks is about a substantial fraction of the world's browsers NOT getting compression benefits from deflate or gzip -- it's not so much about the browsers themselves, but about proxies and firewalls doing things wrong, so "manual compression" is STILL important then!).

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely not an area I've had a lot of experience in, but looking into Django's `ConditionalGetMiddleware` might prove useful.  I think it might help you solve the first of your bullet points.

EDIT: This might be a good place to start: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/conditional-view-processing/